# Получение абсолютного Path

Tags: path, rust

Как получить абсолютный Path в Rust?

Path получаю:

```
let path:PathBuf = {
    let mut dev_path = PathBuf::from("....");
    ...
    ...
    dev_path
};
if let Ok(r) = path.read_link() {
    println!("{:?}", r.to_str());
    ...  обработка r
}
```

На выходе `../../XXX`

Требуется получить абсолютный Path, тость полный обработанный путь без `..`

ОС: `GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два способа.

1. Начиная с Rust 1.5.0, есть метод [`std::fs::canonicalize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.canonicalize.html):

   ```
   use std::fs;
   use std::path::PathBuf;

   fn main() {
       let srcdir = PathBuf::from("./src");
       println!("{:?}", fs::canonicalize(&srcdir));

       let solardir = PathBuf::from("./../solarized/.");
       println!("{:?}", fs::canonicalize(&solardir));
   }
   ```
2. Можно рассчитать путь от [`std::env::current_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/fn.current_dir.html):

   ```
   let relative_path = PathBuf::from("cargo_home");
   let mut absolute_path = try!(std::env::current_dir());
   absolute_path.push(relative_path)
   ```

См. [Getting the absolute path from a PathBuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511331/getting-the-absolute-path-from-a-pathbuf).

Comment: Да, метод fn canonicalize(&self) -> Result<PathBuf>  Присутствует в самом Path и делает именно то что мне надо. Спасибо!